# Where can I get the 64bit Windows Cups drivers?

Tags: samba, drivers, cups

I'm trying to setup a samba print server so that when users add a printer in Windows, the Cups postscript drivers are supplied and installed automatically.

This is working fine for 32 bit Win 7 clients... however, for 64 bit clients, I need the 64 bit drivers.

I have managed to find a copy of the 32 bit drivers using a Gentoo mirror of cups-windows-6.0-source-tar.gz however, all the instructions I can find say that the 64 bit drivers need to be obtained from the Cups SVN which has been offline for a number of weeks now...

Does anyone have a copy of these drivers, or know of any mirrors?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the same driver for any model of printer ? Or can you give a little more work to the network?  ...And, also, the language between cups instances is PS, so any PS driver can directly connect Windows to CUPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in the same situation. Not sure why it's taking so long to restore services.

I did find a copy of the binaries at

https://bitbucket.org/oherrala/puppet/src/933249d58d25/cups/files/drivers/x64

But I'm not entirely sure if those are the newest versions. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look a look on [www.cups.org](http://www.cups.org).
Apparently they suffered a major hardware failure (end of April) and are still running on a temporary backup solution, that may or may not be, complete.
If they need to order new hardware it may take several weeks to get it ordered, delivered and installed in their co-location. Then the software environment needs to be rebuild, security hardened and tested (new hardware may be different form the old stuff so it is probably more complicated than a 1-on-1 restore) before they can put everything back online.
4 to 6 weeks is fairly typical for a scenario like this.

Contact the CUPS team directly if you are really that desperate.
Their is a chance they can provide an alternative.